# rails console OR irb find out the RAILS_VERSION of the current environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Somewhat related to:
[Determine ruby version from within Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589751/determine-ruby-version-from-within-rails)

How to find out the `RAILS_VERSION` from within `rails console`?

Answer (score 6):

Short info in [`Rails.gem_version`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/):

```
Rails.gem_version
# => Gem::Version.new("6.0.1")
```

Long info in [`Rails::Info`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Info.html):

```
Rails::Info
=> About your application's environment
Rails version             6.0.1
Ruby version              ruby 2....
RubyGems version          2.7...
Rack version              2.0...
Middleware                UTF8Cleaner::Middleware, Rack::Cors, ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization, Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, ActionDispatch::Executor, ...
Application root          /home/aaa/bb/app
Environment               development
Database adapter          mysql
Database schema version   20195201212345
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible ways is:

```
pry(main)> Rails.version
=> "5.1.7"
```

or like above was suggested:

```
pry(main)> Rails.gem_version
=> Gem::Version.new("5.1.7")
```

Then you can build some conditions using this technique of versions comparisons:

```
[20] pry(main)> Rails.version.starts_with?('5.1')
=> true
[21] pry(main)> Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) > Gem::Version.new('5.1.2')
=> true
[22] pry(main)> Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) > Gem::Version.new('5.2.3')
=> false
[23] pry(main)> Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) == Gem::Version.new('5.1')
=> false
[24] pry(main)> Gem::Version.new(Rails.version) == Gem::Version.new('5.1.7')
=> true
```

OR

```
[28] pry(main)> Rails.gem_version == Gem::Version.new('5.1.7')
=> true
[29] pry(main)> Rails.gem_version >= Gem::Version.new('5.1.2')
=> true
[30] pry(main)> Rails.gem_version < Gem::Version.new('5.2.2')
=> true
```